# How to remove partial duplicates in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, awk

How can I remove partial duplicates in bash using either awk, grep or sort? 
I did try `sort -u FILE | uniq -w20` but it's not really reliable.

Input:

```
http://www.website.com/1.file
http://www.website.com/2.file
http://www.website.com/3.file
http://www.someotherwebsite.com/1.file
http://www.someotherwebsite.com/2.file
http://www.someotherwebsite.com/3.file
```

Expected Output:

```
http://www.website.com/3.file
http://www.someotherwebsite.com/3.file
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "remove partial duplicates".

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output.  Also, can the solution know in advance what the common text is, or should it discover the longest common string?  Must that string be anchored to the start of the line?  Is it possible that the input would contain multiple different groups with different common parts, or is there a single common string per input?

Comment: @EricRenouf Done. It's a list of url's with similar paths.

Comment: Are there direcotires in the URLs as well, or just host and file?

Comment: @EricRenouf No just host and file.

Answer (score 1):

One solution if all the common strings are well formed like this is to use `awk` and use the first three fields as the key like:

```
awk -F/ '{a[$1$2$3]=$0} END {for(k in a) {print a[k]}}'
```

This will split each line into fields based on `/` as the delimeter.  We use the first 3 fields as the key in an array, and store the whole line as the value.

Once we're done with the input we walk the array and print the value, which will always be the last line that matched the given key.

As suggested, we could make this a bit more flexible by just stripping off the last part and comparing the rest:

```
awk -F/ '{orig=$0; $NF=""; a[$0]=orig} END {for(k in a) {print a[k]}}'
```

which will save the whole line unmodified, make the last field be the empty string, then do the same rest of the array work as before.

Comment: Why not just compare till the last slash `/124.ts`

Comment: @user669761 it now includes a way to do that, good suggestion